# "Carry in" in first full adder

Tags: binary, logic

To anyone who is good with binary/logic gate, where does the first "CIN (carry in)" come from for the first full adder? Trying to make a 32-bit ripple adder from no experience.
[image]

Hopefully the image above helps you figure out what I'm talking about. :)

I did a thorough search but could not find anything related to this, so I thought here would be a great place to start.

Comment: It could be data out to data in.